# Using kendo-ui external file manager

Tags: kendo-ui

I trying to use  kendoui external file manager.

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/general-discussions/why-not-make-image-browser-in-editor-as-separate-controle.aspx#0Hdg62t7dEql6QiANReisg

```
<div id="imgBrowser"></div>

$("#imgBrowser").kendoImageBrowser({
    transport: {
        read: "/service/ImageBrowser/Read",
        destroy: {
            url: "/service/ImageBrowser/Destroy",
            type: "POST"
        },
        create: {
            url: "/service/ImageBrowser/Create",
            type: "POST"
        },
        thumbnailUrl: "/service/ImageBrowser/Thumbnail",
        uploadUrl: "/service/ImageBrowser/Upload",
        imageUrl: "/service/ImageBrowser/Image?path={0}"
    }
});
```

And have following error: http://22.uco.co.il/filebrouser.png

Some one try it?

http://jsfiddle.net/wcze9/85/

Answer (score 0):

One problem you could be having is that according to the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/editor#configuration-imageBrowser.transport.read.contentType), by default, the Read action of the ImageBrowser expects data with a ContentType of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you are returning JSON from the server, it will not be interpreted correctly by the ImageBrowser. Use the example in the documentation to change the contentType expected from the Read action to "application/json":

```
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
<script>
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
  imageBrowser: {
    transport: {
      read: {
        /* omitted for brevity */
        contentType: "application/json"
      }
    }
  }
});
</script>
```